# JPA repository equivalent for Python

Tags: python, java, spring-boot

I was curious to know if, how Spring boot has JPA repository to communicate with databases, Python also has anything similar?

If not, what would be a good way to structure my app such that a service layer would community with a dao layer? An example/demonstration would be great!

Comment: Djangos data model is the closest i can think of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup

Answer (score 1):

As Sahil Chaudhary suggested you can do that as well as using SQLAlchemy as your ORM. I'm sure that flask offers Flask-SQLAlchemy extension that is really easy to set up and use. [This is a small example of it from the Flask docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/queries/#insert-update-delete)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34769177)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python framework such as Django, Flask etc.

ORM provided by these frameworks are quite good and easier to write complex SQL queries.

For instance,
If I have to execute this SQL query to filter all users with name has "stack" keyword, then SQL query & django query will be like -

```
SELECT * from users where name LIKE '%stack%'; // SQL 
Users.objects.filter(name__contains="stack")  // Django
```

The best part about these ORMs is that they allow all of the functionality provided by SQL queries and JPA repository.

You can refer to Django/Flask docs to more info.